# Причастие и деепричастие как однородные члены предложения

Tags: пунктуация, причастия, деепричастия

> Но нагло лжёт источник, пытающийся "развенчать предубеждение", что
>   убийцы - "патриоты России, ревнители престола и хранители чести
>   августейшей семьи" и называя их содомитами. Тогда я скажу: ничто не
>   мешает содомиту быть патриотом. Молодцы ребятки (все ж очень
>   молодые!).

Речь об убийцах Распутина-Новых.

Такое построение фразы ошибочно? Её ничем иначе не спасти, окромя переделывания деепричастия в причастие и закрыв запятой придаточное?

Comment: Здесь всё рушит второй союз "и": ему нечего объединять. Запятую - да, надо на его месте.

Comment: Саша, спасибо! Почему Вы прячетесь в комментах? Проглядела я этот союз, поезд ушёл.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может быть, так:

Но нагло лжёт источник, пытающийся "**развенчать** предубеждение", что убийцы ― "патриоты России, ревнители престола и хранители чести августейшей семьи," **назвав их содомитами.** Тогда я скажу: ничто не мешает содомиту быть патриотом. Молодцы ребятки (все ж очень молодые!).

Пытающийся развенчать (каким способом?) ― назвав их содомитами.

Comment: То есть переделка необходима? Без неё (переделки) никак нельзя прочитать?

Comment: Однородные члены всегда грамматически однородны, то есть относятся к одному и тому же слову и  отвечают на один и тот же вопрос. Поэтому, я думаю, причастие и деепричастие не могут быть однородными.

Comment: Сиби, учи меня жить! ))) Я ничего не знаю про теорию языка.

Comment: Зато пишете интересно, мне нравится.

Answer (score 1):

Изменим порядок слов.

*Источник, пытающийся развенчать предубеждение <...>, нагло лжет, называя их содомитами.*

Comment: Такая  перестановка изменяет смысл, который авторы неуклюже пытаются выразить: причастный оборот у них косвенно относится к содержанию лжи (они, мол, там лживо развенчивают патриотизм и ещё приговаривают: да это просто содомиты). А здесь выходит, что "тот источник, который развенчивает их патриотизм, лжёт в том, что те - содомиты" (но на самом деле _они не содомиты, а патриоты!_). И это выглядит неубедительно: если фильм "Брат" убедил добрую половину населения в том, что патриотом может быть даже серийный убийца, то чем относительно безобидные содомиты хуже?

Comment: Серийный убийца кем угодно может быть, не только патриотом...